# Remove Gridlines in LineChart in Excel using C#.net (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel, linechart

I have a problem in removing/hiding the grid lines in LINE CHART in excel using **C#.Net MVC** with the DLL (**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**) I want to remove it or just hide since it was the client's need. I've seen a lot of article but it's still not working for me.

[Please click here for my sample excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcREc.jpg)

The 3 Numbers in the image is the thing that I want to remove or hide.

And here is my code for Border, ChartArea and PlotArea transparency.

```
  //Plot Area          
            chartPage.PlotArea.Format.Fill.Solid();
            chartPage.PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
            chartPage.PlotArea.Format.Fill.Transparency = (float)1;
  //Chart Area
            chartPage.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Solid();
            chartPage.ChartArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
            chartPage.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Transparency = (float)1;
  //Border
            chartPage.ChartArea.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
            chartPage.ChartArea.Format.Line.Transparency = (float)1;
```

My Problem is the Gridlines, please refer in the image.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Select those object and select the line color as white.
if you don't want the background grid, select all cells and select the background as white.

Comment: I've already did that with my ChartArea and PlotArea and I set it to Transparent. So for the grid it must be transparent too or just remove it. If you can provide a sample code it would be great. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've already found a solution for this problem.

I hope this will help to all of the guys who has the same problem.

[image: Sample Excel]

```
//This will get the X-Axis (#3 in the image)
Axis xAxis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);

//This will get the Y-Axis (#2 in the image)
Axis yAxis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);

//This will delete the Grid Lines (#1 in the image)        
xAxis.MajorGridlines.Delete();
//This will delete the X-Axis (#3 in the image)
xAxis.Delete();
//This will delete the Y-Axis (#2 in the image)
yAxis.Delete();
```

Cheers!